# Will scapular winging effect my lifting performance?

Tags: injury

It seems so that I suffer from scapular winging. I would like to ask, would this reduce my strength on the powerlifting exercises of bench, dead, and rows?

Comment: Depends on the mechanism behind it, no way to tell. The scapula winging (scapula alata) can have neurological, purely muscular, and other causes. That's a question for a medical professional who can assess you properly IMHO

Comment: What does "it seems" mean? Have you been diagnosed by a doctor with winged scapula, or are you just guessing because you're able to see your scapula when you look in the mirror?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly there are quite a few things that can come from this. You will more than likely be a reduction on stability in the shoulder region. When you perform exercises like bench presses, overhead presses, or pull-ups, stability in the shoulder blades is crucial for maintaining proper form and therefore could be dangerous.

You may also find that it limits your shoulder's range of motion. This restriction can make it challenging to perform exercises like shoulder presses or rows. Because of this restriction you might find improper scapular movement can increase the risk of shoulder and back injuries. For instance, bench pressing with scapular winging may strain the shoulder joint or lead to rotator cuff issues.

So get this checked out when you can man.